# Details on Clairvoyance?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What are the specifics on the Clairvoyance spell? I know it shows a path, but like what does dual-casting it do? How do you use it to raise your Illusion skill?

Comment: You can't use it to raise your illusion skill (unless, possibly, there is an aggressive NPC nearby).

Comment: @agf Could you expound more on that, possibly as an answer to this question?

Comment: @galacticninja I don't like to post answers without details / references, but basically spells without reagents only improve skills when used in combat. No powerleveling spell skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it serves any purpose at all other than giving you a direction towards your next marker, as far as leveling, I would assume you would get a few minor points for using the spell, but not necessarily for the spell affecting anything and giving you a damage bonus

Comment: I'll mark this as solved, but still unsure about dual casting.

Comment: not 100% sure, but I think dual casting increases the length of the trail.  Rather useless since you can just move and recast.

Comment: Yep, it increases the length. Albeit it useless, it makes this answer wrong.

Answer (score 16):

It displays a path to an objective. It is illusion school, and I have never unlocked illusion dual-casting. It is very inefficient at raising illusion, if at all it does so. I have never noticed it raise a skill level for illusion - but I have never explicitly checked. It is a more immersive way of playing, with quest markers toggled off, but is naturally less powerful.

It can only display a path when...it can calculate a path, and will not be able to do so when far from basic ground terrain - boulders are not ground terrain. In this case it will fizz and pffft and a message will display that no path was found.

There is an order of priority for the path:

1) A player defined map marker overrides all others. So, be careful to ensure you are following the quest marker and not one you accidentally placed when checking the map

2) When multiple quests are active, I believe it chooses the most recently updated quest.

3) When a quest has multiple different types (e.g. two different NPC) targets only one path (unfortunately) will display. I believe this gives precedence to a lower queststage id of the target. Be careful as, unlike with quest markers on the map, you may not realise that there are alternative ways of completing a quest - even when reading the details of the quest in the journal. Todd's "Morrowind level of quest text detail" claim was nonsense.

4) When a quest has multiple specific objects, e.g. 3 unique books, then it will target the closest. It will not show a path to a non-unique item required (e.g. 10 fire salts) -  the item *instance* must be explicitly defined for the quest (somewhere in the quest files).

I know nothing else about it, and my observations are probably imperfect =)

*EDIT: I forgot to add a point about water. It will try and circumvent water, even if a short swim is quicker, but if it cannot find a path around then it will lead you to the water - but not through the water.*

Comment: Does it work in the dungeons?

Comment: @Bora yes, it works wherever it can find a path along ground tiles nearby. So it won't work if you are airborne, trapped in rocks and so on.

Comment: Re water and boulders: Clairvoyance describes how an NPC would path to the current destination.  It therefore observes lots of constraints to try to make the path "nice" and "reasonable."  For example, it usually prefers leading you to a road or game trail, rather than having you walk through random wilderness.  This works well if the map marker is a standard quest target pointing at a "normal" map object like a cave or dungeon (because there are always trails leading to those things), but less well if you just dropped a custom map marker down wherever.

Answer (score 3):

Duel casting just increases the range of the path shown to your objective. Its probably about twice as long. Doesn't really make all that much difference however, 1 handed does the job fine.